# Create a Calendar (in the ios native calendars) through an Application on the iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to know if it is possible to create a new calendar for your iphone through an application. I know you can set up event with an app, but can I make another calendar through the app to place all the events too.

EDIT:

IF it is not possible what would be the best work around, make a calendar and event store, and save that information with nscoding? Then retrieve afterwards?

If there is a possibilty to create a new calendar to integrate with the existing calendars, that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I have done this:

```
-(NSString*)createCal:(NSString*)myCalId;{
// Instantiate eventstore object
   EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   EKSource *localSource = nil;
   for (EKSource *source in store.sources)
       if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal){
           localSource = source;
            break;
       }

//this is you creating your calendar
EKCalendar *cal;
    cal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:store];
    cal.title = @"Name of calendar";
    cal.source = localSource;
    [store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:nil];
    NSLog(@"cal id = %@", cal.calendarIdentifier);
return cal.calendarIdentifier;}
```

You will need to import `<EventKit/EventKit.h>`
This is powerful so you need to be careful and do a lot of verifications for example if the calendar already exist, and so on.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I added myCalid as a parameter because sometimes you might want to send it a cal id to make sure the calendar was not already created.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/calendars), it doesn't seem possible to create new calendars programatically. However, you can get a list of existing calendars and find out the default calendar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the standard init-Method anymore; it's deprecated. Here the quote from the EKEventStore Class Reference:

"On iOS 5 and later, initialize an event store object with the default init method. On iOS 6 and later, you must request access to an entity type after the event store is initialized with requestAccessToEntityType:completion: for data to return.

On OS X, use initWithAccessToEntityTypes: instead of the default init method. Acceptable entity types are EKEntityMaskEvent for events and EKEntityMaskReminder for reminders."

So if you use iOS6, it's somethin like:

> ```
>     EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:completion:];
> ```

and

> ```
>     cal = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:store];
> ```

I need it for my MacOSX App. So i have to use this:

So in my Case (MacOSX) it's this solution. It's Sparqs code; just modify with the new init instead of the the standard one:

> ```
> -(NSString*)createCal:(NSString*)myCalId;{
> // Instantiate eventstore object
>    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskEvent];
>
>
>    EKSource *localSource = nil;
>    for (EKSource *source in store.sources)
>        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal){
>            localSource = source;
>             break;
>        }
>
> //this is you creating your calendar
> EKCalendar *cal;
>     cal = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:store];
>     cal.title = @"Name of calendar";
>     cal.source = localSource;
>     [store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:nil];
>     NSLog(@"cal id = %@", cal.calendarIdentifier);
> return cal.calendarIdentifier;}
> ```